# cd to an unknown directory name with spaces in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I've looked at some of the posts that have similar issues, but I can't extrapolate some of the solutions to fit my own needs, so here I am.

I have a simple shell script and I need it to cd into a directory with a space in the name. The directory is in the same place every time (`/home/user/topleveldir`) but the directory name itself is unique to the machine, and has a space in it (`/home/user/topleveldir/{machine1}\ dir/`, `/home/user/topleveldir/{machine2}\ dir/`). I'm confused as to the best method to cd into that unique directory in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why something like following would not work

```
baseDir=/home/user/topleveldir
machine=<whatever machine name>
cd "$baseDir/$machine dir"
```

Comment: it is quoted and needs no escape. Just tested it.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the machine name is dynamically generated, so I actually don't know what it is. My current command is grepping the ls of the contents of topleveldir to return the dir I want, but CDing into it is where I'm having trouble. Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: It makes no difference how you assign variable machine. It will still work as long as quoted properly.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I appreciate the feedback. Easy solution, dunno why I didn't think of it myself. Thanks again, and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote that space character, so that the shell knows that it's part of the argument and not a separator between arguments.

If you have the directory directly on that command line in the script, use single quotes. Between single quotes, every character is interpreted literally except a single quote.

```
cd '/home/user/topleveldir/darkstar dir/'
```

If the directory name comes from a variable, use double quotes around the command substitution. **Always use double quotes around command substitutions**, e.g. `"$foo"`. If you leave out the quotes, the value of the variable is split into separate words which are interpreted as glob patterns — this is very rarely desirable.

```
directory_name='darkstar dir'
…
cd "/home/user/topleveldir/$directory_name"
```